# yet another htaccess redirect request - old domain to new domain and old pages to new pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

Spent a day reading through hundreds of variations all over the web but still can't find a definitive answer that works for this.

Moving old site structure on old domain to new site structure on new domain so I am looking for the best, search engine friendly, redirect code that:

1. permanently redirects all old-domain.com and www.old-domain.com traffic to www.new-domain.com.
2. Adds specific redirects from old-domain.com/old-page.html and  www.old-domain.com/old-page.html to www.new-domain.com/new-page/

Here's what I have - and it isn't working - can someone improve/fix this for me please. Many thanks!

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
redirect 301 /old-index.html http://www.new-domain.com/
redirect 301 /old-page-1.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-1/
redirect 301 /old-page-2.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-2/
redirect 301 /old-page-3.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-3/
```

Comment: What's not working about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick with using only mod_rewrite or mod_alias and not mix the two. And order matters

mod_alias:

```
Redirect 301 /old-index.html http://www.new-domain.com/
Redirect 301 /old-page-1.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-1/
Redirect 301 /old-page-2.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-2/
Redirect 301 /old-page-3.html http://www.new-domain.com/new-3/
Redirect 301 / http://www.new-domain.com/
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^old-index.html$ http://www.new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-page-1.html$ http://www.new-domain.com/new-1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-page-2.html$ http://www.new-domain.com/new-2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old-page-3.html$ http://www.new-domain.com/new-3/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Maybe not - I added this to htaccess on old site not new site and seemed ok the old search links mapped through to the new pages properly. But when newsite appeared in listings the links were 404ing on newsite! Have added just the page redirects to newsite htaccess and now seems OK. But what is best practice here? Should I domain redirect to oldsite htaccess and page redirects to newsite htacces or just redirect old domain from the DNS and have the page redirects in place in newsite htaccess? confused!

Comment: @user9373 It doesn't matter, as long as the old URL 301 redirects to the new URL, doesn't matter what server the domain names resolve to

Comment: that's what I thought - but Bing has indexed 

newdomain.com/

as

newdomain.com/oldindexpage.html

and as the redirects wwere in the oldomain htaccess it was 404ing on newdomain!

Comment: It seems to have gone straight for the domain redirect ignoring the page redirects above it and when it's reached newdomain it couldn't find /oldindexpage.html

Comment: @user9373 are you sure it's just not a caching issue?

Comment: no caching involved afaik - oldsite flatfile - newsite straight wordpress installation with yoast seo plugin (flagged but yet to respond to the issue) .. HOWEVER = it seems to make sense to me that if search engines register the domain redirect the page redirects need to be in place newdomain side to direct traffic appropriately ...

Comment: Doh - you mean browser. Nope - caches cleared -the Bing search result URL is actually displayed as newdomain.com/oldindexpage.html and if you click through it 404s if the page redirect is not in place on newdomain htaccess.